# How to customize el-select-v2 filterable function

Tags: vue.js, element-plus

I'm trying to use the `filter-method` to customize the filter options like in the `el-select` component but it doesn't work.
Has anyone managed to make a custom filter for the `el-select-v2` component options?

```
<el-select-v2
      v-model="form.project"
      filterable
      :options="projects"
      placeholder="Select a project"
      style="width: 100%"
      clearable
      :filter-method="filter"
>
```

```js
const projects = computed(() => store.getters['project/projectOptions']);
const filter = (query) => filterOptions(projects.value, query);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find information here
https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus/issues/3606

=> The work around is to use filterable + remote + remote-method.